# Import text from excel file into SQL query

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 17.7 and I'm trying to write script that can read text from an excel file and insert the data (Matterlist #s) as a string into the Declare statement below. I want to avoid having to copy paste each xxxxx-xxxxx number manually into my Declare statement. All I can find are ways to import data from Excel into a SQL table but nothing on how to read text and insert that data into my script. Any suggestions or steps that I could follow to get through this would greatly be appreciated it.

Declare statement:

```
DECLARE @MatterList NVARCHAR(100) = '(XXXXX-XXXXX, XXXXX-XXXXX, XXXXX-XXXXX, XXXXX-XXXXX)'
```

Excel file structure:

```
ID   Client    Matter_Name    Matter_ID
------------------------------------------
1    Client1   Matter_Name1   xxxxx-xxxxx 
2    Client1   Matter_Name1   xxxxx-xxxxx
```

Comment: See [transpose](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to avoid copy and pasting from an excel file into the SQL script. Is there a script that can do that for me?

Comment: You said you found ways to import data from excel into a SQL table. You can also, of course, read from a SQL table. Or you could use a little c# console application and the appropriate nuget packages, or use transpose and then save the excel sheet as text, or any of many other optiions.

Comment: Let's start over. What exactly does "writing a script" mean? Are you using a scripting tool like powershell or sqlcmd? Are you attempting to do this with with TSQL? Have you considered using Excel and vba/macros? How many values exist for Matter_ID in your file? If that number is "many", you probably DO want to import that file as a table and then write a tsql batch to do something with that table.

Comment: @allmhuman. Thank you for your time and assistance. I don't think I can automate the process of inserting matter IDs into my SQL query without using some other application (my apologies) and not sure what the benefit would be to import data from excel into a SQL table if eventually someone has to export that data to copy and paste it into my query manually.

Comment: @SMor. Thank you for your time and attention on this. I'm still learning and I think what I meant by script was query. Yes, I believe I am using TSQL and like you mentioned maybe I can get away with using VBA/macro to get the data in a format that can easily be copy and pasted into my query.